# Calculated column referencing rows in another table

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, database, data-warehouse

I have a table with a column containing formulas referencing items in another table. The table with the formulas looks like this

```html
Formula
A+B
A*B-C
X+Y-Z
...
```

and the look-up table looks like this

```html
Id        Value   
A         10
B         200
C         75
...       ...
```

I want to derive a new column in the table with the formulas, with the result of evaluated expression:

```html
Formula     Result
A+B         210
A*B-C       135
X+Y-Z       5
...         ...
```

Currently the two tables are placed in an SQL Database, with the formula table being quite small (about 300 million rows) and the look-up table being quite large (also about 300 million rows).

Other methods than using SQL are welcome. Actually any method will do, as long as it does the job in an efficient manner. Any ideas for processing such as task?

Comment: This is a really bad idea. That isn't how data in SQL Server, or other RDBMS' work. Storing an expression, that needs to be derived at run time can **only** be done by dynamic SQL, and with something like this open a huge can of worms; as it is very likely to leave you SQL open to injection. You really need to considering redesigning your set up. Perhaps you could achieve this with a CLR function, but that too likely opens a very similar can.

Comment: I agree, that data should not have been placed in a relational database in the first place, but I can not change this setup unfortunately. But as I said, other methods than using SQL are welcome. Any programming language (Python, C, etc) or application on the market.

Answer (score 0):

SQL with a Cursor:

Tables:

```
Create Table #formulas
(
f VarChar(25)
)

Insert Into #formulas Values
('A+B'),
('A*B-C'),
('X+Y-Z')

Create Table #v
(
id char(1),
v Int
)
Insert Into #v Values
('A', 10),
('B', 200),
('C', 75),
('X', 100),
('Y', 110),
('Z', 10)

Create Table #t
(
 f VarChar(25),
 v Float
)
```

Walk through your recs with a Cursor:  Create a dynamic SQL statement and execute into a table #t.

```
Declare @vStr nVarChar(50)
Declare @v1 nVarChar(20)
Declare @op1 nVarChar(20)
Declare @v2 nVarChar(20)
Declare @op2 nVarchar(20)
Declare @v3 nVarchar(20)

Declare vCursor Cursor For
   Select 
      (Select distinct v From #v Where id = Substring(f,1,1)) As 'v1', 
      Substring(f,2,1) As 'op1', 
      (Select distinct v From #v Where id = Substring(f,3,1)) As 'v2', 
      Substring(f,4,1) As 'op2', 
      (Select distinct v From #v Where id = Substring(f,5,1)) As 'v3'
   From #formulas;

Open vCursor
Fetch Next From vCursor Into
@v1,
@op1,
@v2,
@op2,
@v3

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  Begin
      Set @vStr = Case When @v3 Is Null
      Then 'Select '''+ @v1 + @op1 + @v2 + ''',(' + @v1 + @op1 + @v2 + ')'
      Else 'Select '''+ @v1 + @op1 + @v2 + @op2 + @v3 + ''',(' + @v1 + @op1 + @v2 + @op2 + @v3 + ')'
      End
Insert Into #t(f,v)  Execute (@vStr) 
     Fetch Next From vCursor Into
       @v1,
       @op1,
       @v2,
       @op2,
       @v3
  End

   Close vCursor
   Deallocate vCursor

Select * From #t
   Drop Table #formulas
   Drop Table #v
   Drop Table #t
```

Result:

```
f           v
10+200      210
10*200-75   1925
100+110-10  200
```